# Sort by stock and specific product image in Woocommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce

I found a code that inserts in my functions.php that organizes my products for "instock" and in the end "outstock" that's fine, but I have more than 1000 products and some have a general image since they do not have an image of the product, this is called "no2.png", I need to organize my products by stock and do not have the general image "no2.png"

```
class iWC_Orderby_Stock_Status
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        // Check if WooCommerce is active
        if (in_array('woocommerce/woocommerce.php', apply_filters('active_plugins', get_option('active_plugins')))) {
            add_filter('posts_clauses', array($this, 'order_by_stock_status'), 2000);
        }
    }

    public function order_by_stock_status($posts_clauses)
    {
        global $wpdb;
        // only change query on WooCommerce loops
        //SELECT * FROM redpuestosw.galio_posts where ID = '66138';
        if (is_woocommerce() && (is_shop() || is_product_category() || is_product_tag())) {
            $posts_clauses['join'] .= " INNER JOIN $wpdb->postmeta istockstatus ON ($wpdb->posts.ID = istockstatus.post_id ) ";
            $posts_clauses['orderby'] = " istockstatus.meta_value ASC, " . $posts_clauses['orderby'];
            $posts_clauses['where'] = "AND istockstatus.meta_key = '_stock_status' AND istockstatus.meta_value <> ''" . $posts_clauses['where'];
        }
        return $posts_clauses;
    }
}
new iWC_Orderby_Stock_Status;
```

Here is an example of how the previous code is already working, I need those products with that general image to be displayed but the last ones and the products that if they have unique images are shown first, I appreciate your help.

Example image from my web site shop:

[image: Example image from my web site shop]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good afternoon community finally I could solve my problem, I hope this will serve someone who wants to show their products with image and price first.

in function.php of my child theme:

```
/**
* Sorting out of stock WooCommerce products - Order product collections by stock status, in-stock products first.
*/

class iWC_Orderby_Stock_Status
{
public function __construct()
{
// Check if WooCommerce is active
if (in_array('woocommerce/woocommerce.php', apply_filters('active_plugins', get_option('active_plugins')))) {
add_filter('posts_clauses', array($this, 'order_by_stock_status'), 2000);
}
}
public function order_by_stock_status($posts_clauses)
{
global $wpdb;

// only change query on WooCommerce loops
//SELECT * FROM redpuestosw.galio_posts where ID = '66138';
if (is_woocommerce() && (is_shop() || is_product_category() || is_product_tag())) {
  $posts_clauses['fields'] .= " , IF(img.guid REGEXP 'no2.png' , '0' , '1' ) as imagen";

  $posts_clauses['join'] .= " INNER JOIN $wpdb->postmeta istockstatus ON ($wpdb->posts.ID = istockstatus.post_id )";
$posts_clauses['join'] .= "LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta pm ON ($wpdb->posts.ID = pm.post_id AND pm.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id' )";
$posts_clauses['join'] .= "LEFT JOIN $wpdb->posts img ON (pm.meta_value = img.ID)";

  $posts_clauses['orderby'] = "imagen+0 DESC,istockstatus.meta_value ASC, " . $posts_clauses['orderby'];
  $posts_clauses['where'] = "AND istockstatus.meta_key = '_stock_status' AND  istockstatus.meta_key <> '' " . $posts_clauses['where'];
  var_dump( $posts_clauses);
}

return $posts_clauses;
}
}
new iWC_Orderby_Stock_Status;
/**
* END - Order product collections by stock status, instock products first.
*/
```

Add a LEFT JOIN to find the id of the image in postmeta '_thumbmail_id' then with that id add another LEFT JOIN to compare that id with the GUID of posts, then add in the field [fields]: IF (img.guid REGEXP ' no2.png ',' 0 ',' 1 ') as image, where I create a regular expression to find in the guid the name of the non-unique image and I add a' 0 ', if it has a unique image it will have a' 1 ' , so in order by I can order from highest to lowest.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hevZH.png)